# how to save values in a column of pandas dataframe using for loop in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe, I want to add a value of a column(A) index 0 and a value from another column(B) index 1 and want to save the result in column A index 1. I have column B in a dataframe, I tried the below code but it is not working--

```
A = [None] * len(df)
A[0] = A["B"][0]
df["A"] = A

df:

               B    A
   Date     
 2017-09-30   0.0   0
 2017-10-01   1.0   None
 2017-10-02   2.0   None
 2017-10-03   3.0   None
 2017-10-04   4.0   None

for i in range(len(df)-1):
    df["A"][i] = df["A"][i-1] + df["B"][i]
```

Expected Output

```
               B    A
   Date     
2017-09-30    0.0   0
2017-10-01    1.0   1
2017-10-02    2.0   3
2017-10-03    3.0   6
2017-10-04    4.0   10
```

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need first dont create column `A` and use:

```
print (df)
               B
Date            
2017-09-30   0.0
2017-10-01   1.0
2017-10-02   2.0
2017-10-03   3.0
2017-10-04   4.0

df.loc[df.index[0], 'B'] = 0
df['A'] = df['B'].cumsum()
print (df)
              B     A
Date                 
2017-09-30  0.0   0.0
2017-10-01  1.0   1.0
2017-10-02  2.0   3.0
2017-10-03  3.0   6.0
2017-10-04  4.0  10.0
```

Or:

```
print (df)
               B
Date            
2017-09-30  10.0
2017-10-01   1.0
2017-10-02   2.0
2017-10-03   3.0
2017-10-04   4.0

b = df['B'].values.copy()
b[0] = 0
df['A'] = b.cumsum()
print (df)
               B     A
Date                  
2017-09-30  10.0   0.0
2017-10-01   1.0   1.0
2017-10-02   2.0   3.0
2017-10-03   3.0   6.0
2017-10-04   4.0  10.0
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, Thanks for the quick answer! Please have a look at the edited question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Jezrael, your 1st option worked for me.:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pandas try not to use for loops, it just beats the purpose of pandas I think. Maybe you can try something like this:

1. Shift col A up (you can check out the shift function in pandas) and save it as a new col
2. The simply add the newA with col B